# Virtualenv created using a Pipenv environment always has access to site-packages

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv

This might be a bug, but: if I create a virtualenv *while using a Pipenv environment* that virtualenv always has access to site packages for that Pipenv environment.

```
$ pipenv install numpy
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
...
$ pipenv run python -m venv venv  # Default behaviour is not to allow access to site-packages
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ python
Python 3.7.2 (default, May  1 2019, 12:27:28) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>>
```

- Why is this happening?
- Can I avoid it?